# log4net not writing in log

Tags: c#, log4net

I am programming a webform email sending application using C# .Net and i want to record in a log everytime a mail is sent.

Here is my webconfig file

```
   <configSections>
    <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net"/>
  </configSections>


  <log4net>
    <appender name="RollingLogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
      <file value="TestLog.txt"/>
      <appendToFile value="true"/>
      <rollingStyle value="Composite"/>
      <datePattern value="yyyyMMdd"/>
      <maxSizeRollBackups value="10"/>
      <maximumFileSize value="10MB"/>
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="[%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}] [%p] [%c:%L] - %m%n"/>
      </layout>
    </appender>
    <root>
      <level value="DEBUG"/>
      <appender-ref ref="RollingLogFileAppender"/>
    </root>
  </log4net>

 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();
    }
```

I have This attribute under my class definition

```
public partial class enviarMails : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    private static readonly ILog logger = LogManager.GetLogger(MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);
```

And i have this method for writing the log

```
public void escribirLog(String msj) 
        {

            logger.Error(msj);

        }
```

Comment: I added log4net reference trough NuGet

Comment: Most likely the user running your Application Pool does not have write permission to the target log file. Everything else you show looks fine.

Comment: Does the user youre running the site under have write access to your local path? Try some other path, like C:\temp\testlog.txt

Comment: <file value="C:\temp\testlog.txt"/> this?

Comment: @alanrubinoff yes. and you only need to call `XmlConfigurator.Configure()` in app startup, not on each page load.

Answer (score 1):

There are at least 2 things you can change in your code which can make it better/or get it start logging:

1. move the configure call to the startup of your project. Or make it an
   attribute.
2. your TestLog.txt is going into the current directory of running application. You probably do not have any rights in that directory. So change it to a full path of which you know you have rights
3. enable log4net internal debugging to see the internal error for not creating the file. Or to see where it is created.